# отправка сообщения на почту php

Tags: php, email

Пытаюсь отправлять данные на почту через функцию mail, скачал sendmail, прописал к нему путь в php.ini
но при попытке отправить письмо идет в сторону else

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['client-name'];
$number = $_POST['client-number'];


echo $name;
echo "<br>";
echo $number;

if (mail("Privetdiablo3@mail.ru", "Заказ с сайта", "ФИО:".$name.". number: ".$number ,"From: example2@mail.ru \r\n"))
{
    echo "сообщение успешно отправлено";
} else {
    echo "при отправке сообщения возникли ошибки";
}
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Успел разобраться!
неправильно указал с какой почты отправлять письма